# Function x at 0x

Tags: python, function, class

I have an assignment that requires me to get students gpa based off their points and hours. I'm having trouble getting python to return the gpa inside the class I created. This is the Class:

```
class Student:

    """Creates a student with the requirements of names, hours, and points, then
    calculates and returns the specific student's gpa"""

    def __init__(self, name, hours, points):
        self.name = name
        self.hours= float(hours)
        self.points = float(points)
        self.gpa = self.points/self.hours

    def getname(self):
        """Gets the name of the student"""
        return self.name

    def getpoints(self):
        """Get the points of the student"""
        return self.points

    def gethours(self):
        """Get the Hours of the student"""
        return self.hours

    def gpa(self):
        """Gets the GPA of the student"""
        return self.gpa
```

And the code that I use:

```
def main():
    filename = 'student.txt'
    infile = open(filename, 'r')

    gpa = []
    for line in infile:
        name, hours, points = line.split('\t')
        Student(name,hours,points)
        gpa.append(Student.gpa)

    print(gpa)

main()
```

When ran the list returns something along the lines of

> `[<function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>, <function gpa at 0x04AE5780>]`

How would I go about solving something like this so that it would actually return the gpa?

Comment: Why the superfluous getters? Python isn't Java.

Comment: You print the list itself. Try ''.join(gpa)

Comment: Also, `gpa` is a method of `Student`. What output did you expect to see, exactly?

Comment: What does the title of your question  mean?

Comment: Your `self.gpa` getter is shadowing the `self.gpa` field.

Comment: @JackManey while it pains me too to see these sorts of getters and setters in Python,  it is likely that the OP is in some introductory CS course and this is how it is always taught to write classes in such a course (indeed, I bet until recently the course was taught in Java).

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the instance of Student() and use that in your gpa call. You also really don't need the gpa function (it's overwriting the gpa value set in **init**). So, delete the def gpa(self): function and append s.gpa. Something like s=Student(...) and gpa.append(s.gpa)

Comment: The gpa function is returning itself... So it will not matter

Answer (score 0):

```
gpa = []
for line in infile:
    name, hours, points = line.split('\t')
    s = Student(name,hours,points)
    gpa.append(s.gpa())
```

You have to save the result of the `Student` constructor to a variable, and you have to actually call the function `gpa` to get its result

Comment: Except you didn't see what the `self.gpa()` function will return... Hint: Not what the user think it is returning

Answer (score 0):

You're appending `Student.gpa` to the list in the loop, which is a function (aka method) of `class Student`—which is also why it's the same value over and over. You need to create a `Student` instance, i.e.`student = Student(name, hours, points)` and then *call* its `gpa()` method and append the result it returns to the list, i.e. `gpa.append(student.gpa())`.